# read.table only imported partial records

Tags: r, import

I have a CSV file (from sas) with about 100k records, and many values are missing. The missing values are either blank or ".".

After I imported the CSV file into R, the data frame only has about 4k records.

```
> DF <- read.table("aData.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",", na.strings=".")
```

Warning message:

> In scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings, 
>   :   number of items read is not a multiple of the number of columns

I have no clue why this happened. I can open the CSV file in excel without any problem. The last record imputed has nothing special then the record above or below it.

Can anyone give me some help?

Comment: Are you certain that all text fields are quoted? Or that no `"`, `,` etc are lurking within them?

Comment: @GavinSimpson: To be honest, it's hard to tell since there are about 500 columns. However, I can't find any obvious problem. I guess I need to look more closely.

Comment: @RicardoSaporta： Thank you. I tried the one without, but it's the same result.

Comment: How about `read.csv` or `read.delim`. You mentioned it's a csv file, therefore `read.delim( ... , sep = "," )` *might* work.

Comment: I have had cases where read.table did not work but read.csv worked because some text columns contained commas or other punctuation that read.table could not interpet correctly.  I am pretty sure this is exactly what Gavin meant as well.

Comment: @GavinSimpson: Thank you! I checked again, there is a "^Z" in the last line. After I deleted all "^Z" in that csv file, it's imported correctly. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Please remove the answer you edited into your question, and place it in an actual _answer_ below. Then you can accept it, and we can up-vote it!

Answer (score 0):

OP commented:

> With your help, I finally found out that there are several "^Z" [`Ctrl-Z`] inside
>   the CSV file, which causes the problem. After removing all those "^Z",
>   the data was imported correctly.